# Stick the header and footer on Keypad - iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

i am developing a phonegap application for iOS.I want to stick header and footer on top of  the keypad but the body content is scrollable between header & footer.

Can any one tell me how to do that?
Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`iOS` doesn't support `css position:fixed`, you can hide header and footer on text box focus and show on loss of focus.

Comment: Hi Prithvi Raj Nandiwal, thanks for reply. I want header and footer are fixed with scrollable content  on top of the keypad when i press textbox.